# How to detect rfid tag absence with Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, nfc, rfid

I need to scan 2 RFID readers using an Arduino and share the Tag ID over serial. I also need to detect when no tag is on the reader and this will trigger something in my Processing code.

The first part is working, I am currently printing the Tag ID continuously on the serial monitor.

I am not sure how to tackle the second part: how to I detect the absence of a tag? Could I say something like >> if no tag is being read, then send 'no tag' on the serial print?

This is the library I have been using https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid for the RFID-RC522 hardware.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>

#define RST_PIN         9          // Configurable, see typical pin layout above
#define SS_1_PIN        6         // Configurable, take a unused pin, only HIGH/LOW required, must be diffrent to SS 2
#define SS_2_PIN        7          // Configurable, take a unused pin, only HIGH/LOW required, must be diffrent to SS 1

#define NR_OF_READERS   2

byte ssPins[] = {SS_1_PIN, SS_2_PIN};

MFRC522 mfrc522[NR_OF_READERS];   // Create MFRC522 instance.


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  SPI.begin();
  delay(200);

  for (uint8_t reader = 0; reader < NR_OF_READERS; reader++) {
    mfrc522[reader].PCD_Init(ssPins[reader], RST_PIN); // Init each MFRC522 card

    Serial.print(F("Reader "));
    Serial.print(reader);
    Serial.print(F(": "));

    mfrc522[reader].PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();
  }
}


void loop() {

  for (uint8_t reader = 0; reader < NR_OF_READERS; reader++) {

    // Look for new cards
    if (mfrc522[reader].PICC_IsNewCardPresent() && mfrc522[reader].PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {

      dump_byte_array(mfrc522[reader].uid.uidByte, mfrc522[reader].uid.size);
      Serial.println();

      // Halt PICC
      // mfrc522[reader].PICC_HaltA(); (I have commented this in order to print continously not just once)
      // Stop encryption on PCD
      mfrc522[reader].PCD_StopCrypto1();

    }
  }

}

/**
   Helper routine to dump a byte array as hex values to Serial.
*/
void dump_byte_array(byte *buffer, byte bufferSize) {
  for (byte i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
    Serial.print(buffer[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : "");
    Serial.print(buffer[i], HEX);
  }
}
```